# Error in integrating QR code scanner with Zxing

Tags: android, qr-code

I am trying to integrate a QR code scanner into my android app with Zxing. I have followed these steps:

1. I have downloaded ZXing.zip file and extract it.
2. Open the ZXing project as an android existing project and then go to android folder and open the android folder and also include core.jar file into the ZXing project named CaptureActivity.
3. I have used the CaptureActivity project as a library in my project named 'QRCodeSample'.

This is my MainActivity.java file:

```
package com.charith.qrcodesample;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button b1;
    TextView scanResult;
    String contents;
    public static final int REQUEST_CODDE = 1;
    protected static final String QR_CODE_MODE = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bScan);
        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
                intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE",QR_CODE_MODE);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
            }
        });
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        scanResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvContent);
        if(requestCode == 0) {
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
                String format = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");
                scanResult.setText(contents);
            }else if(resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED){
                scanResult.setText("Error");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

This is my AndroidManifest.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.charith.qrcodesample"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="10" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.charith.qrcodesample.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And this is my main_activity.xml file.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bScan"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
        android:text="Scan" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvContent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/bScan"
        android:layout_below="@+id/bScan"
        android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
        android:text="" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I've checked my app using the emulator in eclipse. Then I've got the following error:

```
The application has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again
```

It would be much appreciated if anyone could clarify this problem as soon as possible.

Comment: The Android emulator in Eclipse does not have support for the camera. Is it possible that the emulator is not working because of lack of camera support? I would test this application on a working Android device before chalking this error up to a code error; most likely it is just an Android Emulator/Eclipse related issue.

Answer (score 1):

First, you've copied and pasted our project. I assume you have copied the UI too. As you may see in many issues here, and as discussed in https://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/LicenseQuestions , this is not permitted by the open source license.

Second, you've copied and pasted the `AndroidManifest.xml` declarations. You are declaring an `Activity` in our namespace and intercepting our `Intent`s. This is going to interfere with our app, and is not OK. Remove this and create your own manifest.

But third, you seem to be trying to integrate by `Intent`. It's much easier than this, and has nothing to do with copying and pasting all this stuff *incorrectly*. See https://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningViaIntent

Comment: Thanx Sean.I've tried to do this but it doesn't work.Actually it's not very clear because I am new to the Android.I would be really very appreciated if you could explain it in step by step.Thanx again for your kind responce.

Comment: What have you tried? There is little to explain. Add the jar file and use the code on that wiki.